# If I request a chargeback on a purchase because a company went bankrupt, who foots the bill?

Tags: credit-card, banking, refund, chargeback

One reason people often cite when advising to make purchases with credit cards is the ability to issue a chargeback in case of problems. A common example would be buying airline tickets and then the airline going bankrupt.

My question is, who foots the bill in such cases, and why? The airline can't (or else they'd just issue the chargeback directly) so it seems only the credit card company is left. Do they really cover the bill? If so, are they doing it only to maintain good relations with their customers or is there some other reason behind it? When the payment is made with a standard wire transfer, banks seem not to be so eager to issue a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The general structure of credit card transactions is:

> 1. Card holder swipes at supplier's store
> 2. Supplier processes the transaction with the credit card processor ("their bank")
> 3. Processor submits it to the network (Visa, Mastercard, etc), which then routes it to the bank that issued the credit ("issuer")
> 4. Issuer pays the processor through the network and charges the card holder's account.

Chargeback, as the name suggests, works exactly the same in the opposite direction.

For merchants which have large volumes of transactions, the money is removed from the pool of payments they haven't yet received from their processor. Sometimes, they may have not received your own payment yet, sometimes its an unlucky purchaser's money who paid closer to the insolvency time.

Other times merchants provide guarantees to their credit card processor, and the guarantor then pays.

And sometimes the credit card processor pays from their own money, and adds it to the debt they'll try to collect from the merchant.

Answer (score 1):

Chargebacks are always pre-financed by your bank (the one that handles your credit card).
The bank can turn around and work with the supplier to get their money back, and if it doesn’t work out, they ‘suck it up’ and simply lost that amount.
(Actually, in practice, for small amounts they often don’t even bother to try; it’s cheaper to take the loss than to endure the processing cost)

Remember that credit card transactions come with a fee that the supplier pays and the bank gets; this covers their losses easily; they still make a killing, which is why they are so eager to provide you a credit card.

Comment: No actually. *your* bank will **never** eat the cost. It would be *their* (supplier's) bank.